# How to find pattern in file and comment that pattern in file using python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to search pattern in file from "COMPRESS" till ")" and comment it.

My input file as below :

```
CREATE MULTISET TABLE TESTDB.testTbl ,FALLBACK ,
     (
      Local_Pd BIGINT NOT NULL,
      Year_Id INTEGER NOT NULL,
      par_t CHAR(15) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      PB_Ind INTEGER COMPRESS(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,6))
UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX ( Local_Pd ,Year_Id ,par_t,
       PB_Ind);
```

Output file :

```
CREATE MULTISET TABLE TESTDB.testTbl ,FALLBACK ,
     (
      Local_Pd BIGINT NOT NULL,
      Year_Id INTEGER NOT NULL,
      par_t CHAR(15) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      PB_Ind INTEGER /* COMPRESS(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,6) */  )
UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX ( Local_Pd ,Year_Id ,par_t,
       PB_Ind);
```

Comment: I am able to delete it using RE but not able to wrap the matched patterns with /* and */

Comment: Please add your code to question.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
import re

test_str = "CREATE MULTISET TABLE TESTDB.testTbl ,FALLBACK , ( Local_Pd BIGINT NOT NULL, Year_Id INTEGER NOT NULL, par_t CHAR(15) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC, PB_Ind INTEGER COMPRESS(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,6)) UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX ( Local_Pd ,Year_Id ,par_t, PB_Ind);"

regex = r"(COMPRESS\([^\)]*\))"
t=re.sub(regex, r"/* \1 */", test_str)
print(t)
```

Comment: Thanks. Will it work for file or should I read line by line to do the same?

Comment: how to handle if COMPRESS and ) has mutilple lines in between. How to handle multiline.  eg  COMPRESS(1,2,3,                                                                                    ..
..
4,5,6)

Comment: It should work with entire file and handle multi-lines.